# Template "data" binding provides value instead of an observable

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I'm trying to use a template binding with its "data" bound to an observable. However, $data for controls inside the template is receiving "value of the observable" (and not the observable itself.)

Since I get the value, and not the observable, I'm unable to set up a 2-way binding if I'm using a template. If I set up a direct binding, the same code works without issue.

Here's a jsfiddle that highlights my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8cDLw/

**HTML**

```
Working Example: <div id="workingExample">
    <select data-bind="options: _.range(0,24), hour: MyDate"></select>
    Selected Value is: <span data-bind="text: MyDate" />
</div>

<br/>Non-Working Example: <div id="notWorkingExample" data-bind="template: { name: 'hour-template', data: MyDate }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="hour-template">
    <select data-bind="options: _.range(0,24), hour: $data" />
    Selected Value is: <span data-bind="text: $data" />
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hour = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, addBindingsAccessor) {
        var $el = $(element);
        var curDate = valueAccessor();

        if (!ko.isObservable(curDate)) {
            console.log("Failure: Input Not an observable object. Data type found: " + typeof curDate + ", value: " + curDate);
        }
        $el.val(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(curDate).getHours());

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
            var currentDate = valueAccessor();
            var hour = $el.val();
            var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(currentDate);
            date.setHours(hour);

            if (ko.isObservable(currentDate))
                currentDate(date);
            else
                console.log("Cannot update value. Input not an observable.");
        });
    }
};

var viewModel = function()
{
    this.MyDate = ko.observable(new Date("2013-11-08T06:27:00.000Z"));
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), document.getElementById("notWorkingExample"));
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), document.getElementById("workingExample"));
```

Note the 2 divs declared: "workingExample" and "notWorkingExample" are being bound to a new instance of same viewModel (which contains one observable: a hardcoded date.)

workingExample binding is a regular custom binding receiving an observable... in this case, to manipulate "hour" part of a date (which works... i.e. if I change dropdown value, it updates the "hour" in datetime field.)

In NotWorkingExample, I'm passing the observable as "data" to a template (and trying to then use that observable witha binding identical to workingExample.)

I'm clearly missing something here, because NotWorkingExample, from my perspective, should be functionally equivalent to workingExample... the only difference being that instead of directly binding the value, I'm passing the value through template -> "data" binding.

The idea here is to have another `<select>` in template to have a 2-way "minute" binding as well etc. to essentially build a custom control using the template.

Can you please point out what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Looking at my example, realized that I was unnecessarily complicating things:

Here's a much simpler jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kkC5/

Any thoughts on either implementations? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using the `data` option to a template, KO automatically unwraps it for you and grabs a dependency, so the template updates when the observable data changes.

KO 3.0 does have a new `$rawData` context variable that is intended to give you the original observable in cases where KO has unwrapped it as part of creating a new context.  However, in this case the `template` binding already unwraps the `data` option itself. This appears to be a case that we could improve in KO, as ideally `$rawData` would be the right choice here.

So, in your specific case, you can choose to pass an object literal with your observable as a property like:

`template: { name: 'mytmpl', data: { myDate: MyDate } }`

Then, you can reference the observable using `myDate` or whatever you want to call the property.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/a6vtD/

Just as a side note, in your fiddle you had some cases of `<span />` and `<select />`. This can cause issues in your bindings, as they are not self-closing tags in HTML5.  You will want to use `<span></span>` and `<select></select>`.

Comment: Thank you. It's an easy enough change. +1 (if I could) for mentioning self-closing span/select issue.

Comment: I've had [a pull request](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1415) to fix this issue ($rawData broken within 'template' and 'with' bindings) open since May - it would be great if you could take a look!